# Reset the password for root in oracle cloud Ubuntu

Tags: virtual-machine, cloud, oracle-linux

I managed to get my VM upp and running on oracle cloud Linux. What i wanted to ask is how do i reset the root password for the VM after logging in with my SSH key? i got this when trying.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-instance2:~$ su -
Password:
su: Authentication failure
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ passwd root
passwd: You may not view or modify password information for root.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Have you try to switch to `root` on this way: `sudo su -`?

Comment: thanks that worked!
Do i need to change passwd on root or what would be recommended`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use command like:

```
sudo su -
```

to become root. You can change the `root` password only if you want to access directly (via `ssh` for example) files, owned by this user. In 98% of the cases you do not need to become `root` user or access directly files with only root access. You can use always commands like:

```
sudo command parameters
```